# Snowflake: Execution error in store procedure : SQL compilation error: Object does not exist or not authorized. At Statement.execute

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm totally confused by the permission model of the Snowflake system.  I created a database, created a stored procedure within that database, and tried to call that stored procedure all with the same user in the SYSADMIN role.  I get the error "Execution error in store procedure: SQL compilation error: Object  does not exist or not authorized. At Statement.execute"

I'm not even sure where to start.  How does my user not have permission to a table that was created by said user?

[image: Screenshot of procedure and error message]

[image: Second Screenshot w/ Database structure visible.]

Comment: Did you create the table that the sp and the error are referring to?

Comment: Yes.  I believe I've created everything in this Snowflake account with the same user under the SYSADMIN role.

Comment: Can you see the table if you use `show tables`

Comment: Yes, the table shows up, and it's owner is SYSADMIN.  This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Check the casing of the name of the objects you are referring to. If you for example created the table wrapped in double quotes, it's case sensitive. Snowflake automatically converts unquoted identifiers to UPPER case.

Example:

```
    CREATE TABLE test1 (
    test nvarchar)

    CREATE TABLE "teSt2" (
    test nvarchar)

   -- This works
    select * from test1

   -- This doesn't work because the table was created wrapped in double quotes and with a capital S in the name
    select * from test2

   -- This doesn't work either because it will convert to UPPER
    select * from teSt2

   -- This works
    select * from "teSt2"
```

Comment: I was really hoping that was going to be the answer!  Alas, it wasn't.  I'm editing the original post with a second screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be a problem with the case sensitivity of the table but it might be related to the rights of the stored procedure (Function) you created.

Changing your code as below might do the trick.

```
EXECUTE AS OWNER -- Present
EXECUTE AS CALLER -- Change
```

To understand more on owner's rights and caller's right of the Stored Procedure, please follow below link.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure **returns a single row that contains a single column**; it is not designed to return a result set. However, if your result set is small enough to fit into a single value of type VARIANT or ARRAY, you can return a result set from a stored procedure with some additional code- [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#returning-a-result-set)

Hope this helps!

It works for delete statement! Example below:

```
use role sysadmin;
create or replace database DATA_IMPORTS_SO;
create or replace table ProductMaster_SO (id integer, name varchar);
insert into ProductMaster_SO values (1,'stackoverflow');
insert into ProductMaster_SO values (2,'stackoverflow');
select count(*) FROM DATA_IMPORTS_SO.PUBLIC.ProductMaster_SO;--2 rows
create or replace procedure Clenup_DI_Products()
returns string not null
language javascript
EXECUTE AS OWNER
as
$$
var sql_command = 
     "delete FROM DATA_IMPORTS_SO.PUBLIC.ProductMaster_SO";
    try {
        snowflake.execute (
            {sqlText: sql_command}
            );
        return "Succeeded.";   // Return a success/error indicator.
        }
    catch (err)  {
        return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
        }
$$;

call Clenup_DI_Products();
select count(*) FROM DATA_IMPORTS_SO.PUBLIC.ProductMaster_SO;--0 rows
```

Comment: I'm actually only having the procedure return the original Select statement, not the result set.

I'm getting an error accessing the table itself.  I was trying to get this simple select to work before delving deeper into the true purpose of this Cleanup proc.

Comment: I have not granted any privileges to the user on the table or procedure. and was able to execute an SP using the table that is created with the same user (SYSADMIN).

Can you give it a shot to execute the code above and let us know if you face the error?

Comment: That definitely works.  I'm able to run the newly created stored proc with no issues.

Comment: I still can't figure out why the existing proc/table isn't working.  Best I can tell everything is owned by SYSADMIN, although I don't see anywhere to see who owns the proc.

I even dropped the proc, and created it again with a use role sysadmin; command.  Still no access to that table.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I was unable to find a reason that the stored procedure wouldn't work.  I ended up dropping the table and recreating it with an all caps name.  After that I was able to run the stored procedure with no issues.

I'm unclear if the fix was creating the table with a UCASE name or recreating it with a USER ROLE SYSADMIN command.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check.

1. Enclose the table name in double-quotes. Check case.
2. GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "SCHEMA_NAME" TO ROLE PUBLIC;